# Shell script Execute file in tmp directory

Tags: linux, shell, execute

I am trying to execute shell script which i have created in tmp folder.
i have granted permission as well to the script using command below.

```
chmod a+x tmp/test/test.sh
```

when i run the code i get permission denied error.

```
[root@server test]# ./test.sh
-bash: ./test.sh: Permission denied
```

Comment: What is in the `#!` line of `test.sh`?

Comment: You shouldn't do your testing while logged in as root? A mistake can wipe out your whole system.

Comment: Try `findmnt --target test.sh` and see if the `noexec` mount option is mentioned.

Comment: You might get more details / isolate some issues with something like `bash -x ./test.sh`

Comment: @Barmar its set to #!/bin/bash,   this is my development box which we recreate every week.

Comment: @alaniwi, you are right i see noexec in there.   /tmp   tmpfs  tmpfs  rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel

Answer (score 2):

The issue may cause by tmp is noexec, and you can use the sh command to execute the the shell script

sh ./test.sh

Answer (score 1):

Try this workaround:

```
(. tmp/test/test.sh)
```